# jquery blockUI tell if page or specific element is blocked

Tags: jquery, blockui

Is there a way to tell if $.blockUI(); has been called but $.unblockUI() has not been called?  Ideally this should be able to work for both blocking the full page and specific elements.

I'd expect it to work something like this

```
> $.blockUI();
> $.isBlockUI?():
>> true
> $.unblockUI();
> $.isBlockUI?();
>> false
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look what I found [here](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#demos)

```
  $(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#demo14').click(function() { 
        $.blockUI({ 
            fadeIn: 1000, 
            timeout:   2000, 
            onBlock: function() { 
                alert('Page is now blocked; fadeIn complete'); 
            } 
        }); 
    });
```

Evidently there's one for Block and unBlock sorta like a onSuccess function.  So on the onBlock function you'd simply just set a global boolean value.

Hope this helps!

Happy Coding! ;)

Answer (score 31):

```
var data = $('#element').data();
//will return Object like: { blockUI.isBlocked=1, blockUI.onUnblock=null} 

if (data["blockUI.isBlocked"] == 1)
// is blocked
else
// is not blocked
```

Comment: Agreed. It more directly answers the question.

Answer (score 4):

I use a more primitive hack :

```
var isUIBlocked = $('.ui-widget-overlay:visible').length > 0;

if(isUIBlocked){
  // something is displayed with an active overlay, hence stop
}
```

This works for me even when using `.dialog()` with `modal:true`

Comment: Can you tell if a SPECIFIC element is blocked?  That's half the question asked.  (I know this is super old.  Was just looking for the answer myself.)