# How to tell if jQuery BlockUI is blocking the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-blockui

Very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907013/jquery-blockui-tell-if-page-or-specific-element-is-blocked), except I'm not blocking a particular element, I'm blocking the whole page.

So instead of:

```
$('div.test').block({ 
    message: '<h1>Processing</h1>', 
    css: { border: '3px solid #a00' } 
});
```

I'm doing:

```
$.blockUI({ 
    message: $('#divModal1'), 
    css: { cursor: 'default' }
});
```

I've tried using `html` and `body` as the selector..

```
var data = $('html').data();

if (data['blockUI.isBlocked'] == 1) {
    alert('blocked');
}
else {
    alert('not blocked');
}
```

But `data['blockUI.isBlocked']` is always 'undefined'

Comment: Something like `var isClosed = $(".blockOverlay").length===0);` ?

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about using the blockui css to check if blocked. Thanks, might be the way

Comment: You can make that an answer if you want. I'm using it, works perfect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I reviewed the source; it looks like the data is being written to `window`, not to `html` or `body`. See fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/nAQ94/

```
$.blockUI({ 
    message: $('#divModal1'), 
    css: { cursor: 'default' }
});

console.log($(window).data());
```

The `console.log` call returns the following object:

`> Object {blockUI.history: Object, blockUI.onUnblock: null, blockUI.isBlocked: 1}`